# How to set a dynamic validation with new form control

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular-reactive-forms

I have an object that should build a form

```js
const textBox = {
  fontColor: 'red',
  fontSize: '20',
  placeholder: 'name',
  name: 'input name',
  label: 'mohamed',
  validation: {
    required: true
  }
};
```

I created a simple dynamic form but I need to set the validators with each form control

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  const inputDataObj = {} as any;
  for (const prop of Object.keys(this.InputObj)) {
    debugger;
    if (prop !== 'validation') {
      inputDataObj[prop] = new FormControl(this.InputObj[prop]);
      this.inputProps.push(prop);
    }
  }
  this.form = new FormGroup(inputDataObj);
}
```

now I need to set validation to any form control, the validation is an optional property,
some objects may not have any validations

Comment: What have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you'd like to add validation only when the `required` property in your `validation` object is set to true.

If so, you want to first create the `FormControl` and then use the `addValidators` method to dynamically add validation:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

const textBoxes = [
  {
    fontColor: 'red',
    fontSize: '20',
    placeholder: 'name',
    name: 'input name',
    label: 'mohamed',
    validation: {
      required: true,
    },
  },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public form = new FormGroup({});
  ngOnInit(): void {
    for (const textbox of textBoxes) {
      const control = new FormControl(textbox.placeholder);
      if(textbox.validation.required){
        control.addValidators(Validators.required);
      }
      this.form.addControl(textbox.name, control);
    }
  }
}
```

[Stacblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gsimzi?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

// Your component

```
  ngOnInit() {

const textBoxes = [
  {
    fontColor: 'red',
    fontSize: '20',
    placeholder: 'name',
    name: 'input name',
    label: 'mohamed',
    validation: [
      required: true,
      min: 5,
    ],
  },
];

    this.createForm(textBoxes);
  }    

  createForm(controls: YourModel[]) {
    this.formGroup = this.service.toFormGroup(controls);
  }
```

// service (is better if you split your functionality in a service)

```
  validatorsMap = {
    required: () => Validators.required,
    min: (num: number) => Validators.min(num),
    ... etc: etc(),
    ... etc: etc(),
  };


  toFormGroup(inputs: YourModel[]): FormGroup {

      const group: any = {};

      inputs.forEach(input => {

          const validations: any[] = this.getValidators(input);

          group[input.name] = new FormControl(
            '', // initial value
            validations// here are that you want!
          );
        });

      return new FormGroup(group);

  }

  getValidators(input: ControlModel) {

    return input.validation
      .map(validation => {
        return fn = this.validatorsMap[validation.name];
      });
  }
```